# What's a good way to send changes to an object over a socket?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a system for synchronising changes in objects over TCP. I want this to be a generic system that I can use for a number of different objects. An object in this case is a set of key-value pairs, an array of objects, or a map of strings to objects. The object structure rarely changes, but the values change multiple times per second.

I'm trying to implement something that just sends the changes instead of serializing the entire object every time it changes so that I can reduce bandwidth requirements and reduce latency.

What I'm thinking of right now is turning something like this:

`[ { a: 5, b: "abc"}, { a: 3, b: "xyz" } ]`

into a set of 1-dimensional arrays:

`values = [ 5, "abc", 3, "xyz" ]
objects = [ { a: 0, b: 1 }, { a: 2, b: 3 } ]
conainer = [ [ 0, 1 ] ]`

The integers point to another element in one of the three arrays. Which elements point to what is sent in advance and shouldn't change. When a value changes, the only thing that needs to be sent is the index in the value array and the new value.

I get the feeling that I'm massively over-thinking this (read: I'm pretty sure I'm making this a million times more complicated than it needs to be). This would be really easy if I could hard-code the object-structure. I started implementing the system described above, but it's getting so complex that I feel like there must be an easier way to do this, that does not involve re-sending the entire object when it changes.

**Edit:** Seems like I didn't explain myself very well. I'll have another go:

I need to send changes to an object/model/datastructure/whatever you want to call it (I use object in the rest of this post) over the internet. Since the values in the objects change a lot, but the structure rarely does I just want to send the changes, not serialize the entire object every single time and send the entire thing over the network if one single integer increases by one.

This object does not have a know structure at compile time, so I can't hardcode it. At runtime the structure is known, and only the values will change a lot.

An object may, for example, look like this:

```
Foo {
    int a, b, c
}

Bar {
    Foo[] foos = { ... }
    int a, b, c
}

Baz {
    map<string, Bar> bars = { ... }
}
```

This structure will be known before sending the changes, and will not change while the program is running, but isn't known at compile time. (it can be changed by the user)

Comment: Have you considered JSON?

Comment: I don't quite follow. You want to send only the changes in different types of objects, of which there could only be 3 types. Can there be multiple object of a given type? If so, what is the id? Can you combine multiple objects in a single transmission? What you're doing is a compression scheme, those can get complex pretty quickly. How important is saving bandwidth? Are you on a low bandwidth network? If not, sending the whole object might not be a big deal.

Comment: Also, multi-threading and concurrency become big issues, especially when sending differential changes

Comment: You may use binary serialization and use a differential compression (or delta compression) library.

Comment: Eris, @Jack BeNimble: I'd prefer not to send the whole object. Especially because this will be one server to many clients. If there are 100 clients connected I don't want to be sending 100kb/sec to each of them while it could be 1kb/sec. It's mostly only sending changes from the server to the clients, and the clients can't directly change anything without going through the server. I've tried to clarify what I'm trying to do, please see my edit.

Comment: @Graffito: I know I'm going to sound like I'm crazy by saying this, but: This is a system that will connect to code that's written in 3 different (excluding C#) languages. One of those languages does not have support for basically any library. If I'm going to have to port some massive codebase to this language, I'm going to drive myself crazy (not to mention how slow this would run) so using some existing compression library is impossible.

Comment: Did you already define: **1)** a method to identify all items of an object **2)** methods to serialize items ? **3)** methods to compare 2 items content. In that case, differential update could be quite simple: you just need a flag for each serialized  item that indicates whether it has changed (the item content is then added to buffer) or not (no data added to buffer).

Comment: @Graffito: 1) I'm using Lists and Dictionaries to store the items in an object, so yes I can iterate over all of them. 2) Yep 3) I was thinking of pushing the changes made to an object onto a list, and using that list to determine what's changed. It sounds pretty easy, but I'm having trouble seeing how I'd match those flags to a certain element somewhere a few levels deep in the object structure. I'd really appreciate it if you could explain that part in more detail. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Can you wrap the code in three languages as clients, which live on the server,  to a restful service (also on the server) via JSON? Then apply the compression code using C# and send it to the (remote) clients?

Comment: @JackBeNimble: I could do that, but then I'd still have to port the decompression library for the remote clients, right?

Comment: Maybe not. If you have the receiving remote client service written in C# to do the decompression, then send the decompressed stream to each of the remote clients wrapped in their respective services to receive the JSON data.

Comment: @JackBeNimble: Ah I see what you mean. That would save me an awful lot of work indeed. Unfortunately, it's not possible to run a C# client (or anything else besides the application that needs to receive the data, for that matter) on every remote client.

Comment: So the remote client is something that you can't introduce changes to? But how will you modify them to understand your own, hand-rolled compression protocol? Or your able to modify them and just not add new applications? Why is it so restrictive - policy or are the remote nodes just so limited?

Comment: @JackBeNimble: Yes, the way this is set up means that I can't run any additional programs. I can change the code that runs on the clients, but that's the only thing I can do.

Comment: That's harsh. It sounds like you'll need to modify the code. How does the receiving client know the type of object it's receiving?

Comment: @JackBeNimble: The structure will either be sent to the client before sending the rest, or the client could use a cached version if there is one.